# (Swift + Firebase) Convert observeSingleEvent to observe .childAdded

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a observeSingleEvent in my viewDidLoad function and I want to change it into a observe with .childAdded so that it will listen constantly and add the objects whenever they get added to the database.

Here's the code that reads from firebase:

```
let parentRef = Database.database().reference().child("Recipes")

    parentRef.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { snapshot in

        // PROCESSES VALUES RECEIVED FROM SERVER
        if ( snapshot.value is NSNull ) {

            // DATA WAS NOT FOUND
            print("– – – Data was not found – – –")

        } else {

            // DATA WAS FOUND
            for user_child in (snapshot.children) {

                let user_snap = user_child as! DataSnapshot
                let dict = user_snap.value as! [String: String?]

                // DEFINE VARIABLES FOR LABELS
                let recipeName = dict["Name"] as? String
                let recipeDescription = dict["Description"] as? String

                food.append(Element(name: recipeName!, description: recipeDescription!))

                self.tableView.reloadData()
            }
        }
    })
```

Another problem that I have now (besides that it only loads once) is that whenever I go to another view in the app and then come back it reads everything again so I get duplicates of everything in my tableView, will that still happen with the observe?

Edit:

Here is what my database looks like:

```
Recipes
   -Kv7FAqgLtDrRoyGd-99
       Description: "food description" 
       Name: "food name" 
   -KvBuzMUnIQXn8gpG2WL
       Description: "food description2"  
       Name: "food name2"  
   -KvH6yYeJaThK7oP8xBj
       Description: "food description3"  
       Name: "food name3"
```

Comment: Simply write `parentRef.observe(value, ....)` instead - this will make the query continous.

Comment: @matiastofteby Thanks, it worked, however it still duplicates the objects, it reloads everything over and over again whenever viewDidLoad is run, how can I fix that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Change observeSingleEvent to observe.
2. Empty food array whenever observing new values.
3. Reload your food array outside your for-loop so that you only reload whenever you have loaded all of your items into your array.

   ```
   let parentRef = Database.database().reference().child("Recipes")

   // 1. Change to observe
   parentRef.observe(.value, with: { snapshot in

      // PROCESSES VALUES RECEIVED FROM SERVER
      if ( snapshot.value is NSNull ) {

          // DATA WAS NOT FOUND
          print("– – – Data was not found – – –")

      } else {

          // 2. Empty food array
          self.food = []

          // DATA WAS FOUND
          for user_child in (snapshot.children) {

              let user_snap = user_child as! DataSnapshot
              let dict = user_snap.value as! [String: String?]

              // DEFINE VARIABLES FOR LABELS
              let recipeName = dict["Name"] as? String
              let recipeDescription = dict["Description"] as? String

              food.append(Element(name: recipeName!, description: recipeDescription!))

           }
           // 3. reload tableview outside loop
           self.tableView.reloadData()
       }
   })
   ```

By emptying your food array whenever observing new values you ensure to only show the values that are present in your database and thus never having repetitive elements.

Comment: Glad to help :=)

Comment: How can I take this approach that uses a query, but be able to listen for new items to append without deleting/removing what is at index 0? So my chats may have 10,000+ messages. I want to display the last 100 but be able to add to that while in a chat & manually remove.

Comment: You should ask a new question so others may find the answer to it as well.